# NGINX OCSP stapling not working when CRL enabled?

Tags: nginx, certificates

I have an NGINX proxy set up to do OCSP stapling so new certificates work in google chrome.

I also set up client certificate checks on NGINX.

when I use the ssl_crl module to check the client certificates against the CRL, OCSP stapling will be disabled by NGINX and I get a Certificate Transparency Error in Google Chrome.

How can I have OCSP Stapling with CRL in parallel? Is this possible?

Here the relevant extract from my NGINX config:

```
    # OCSP Stapling
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;

    # Trusted Certs for OCSP Stapling and Client Cert Check
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/trustedCAs.pem;

    # Server certificates
    ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/certs/mycert.cer;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/certs/mycert.key;
    ssl_password_file /etc/nginx/keys/cert-pw.pass;

    # Verify Client Certificate
    ssl_verify_client on;
    ssl_verify_depth 2;
    ssl_client_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_crl /etc/nginx/certs/revoked.crl;
```

Comment: Have you provided a `resolver` statement here or elsewhere higher in configuration? It is required as far as I remember.

Comment: If you already do OCSP, you neither not need nor should check a CRL

Comment: @LapshinDmitry Yes, I provided a resolver. When I omit the CRL module, OCSP stapling is working and I can see in the firewall logs that the public OCSP responder is getting a request.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I need the CRL for checking the revocation of the client certificate. I think OCSP can only check the server certificate. Those are different CAs in my case. If I can do OCSP stapling for the client cert as well that would be ideal.